# Events in JSP?

Tags: events, jsp

I'd like to ask if there is in the JSP events such as the swing (eg: ActionEvent)?

Answer (score 1):

No. There are not.

If you want something similar (not equal), you could give [JSF](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/) a try for your Java based web applications.

Answer (score 1):

Events on the client side are to be handled by javascript.  If you need to send any information back to the server, use AJAX or a `<form>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you like Swing programming and want to continue this paradigm even in Web applications then I suggest you take a look at [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/).